# Compass stop checking sprites

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite

Is there a method or configuration setup to have Compass not check sprites everytime?

I know it doesn't actually regenerate the sprites but even the check compass does to see if sprites have changed or not are currently making the compilation 2.3 seconds longer. Our sprites aren't even that big. It would be nice if can set some variable on wheter compass checks sprites or not. The won't change that much anyway.

It's a big difference if the compilation takes 400ms or 3.1 seconds....

After searching Google I can't find any methods apart from copying the sprite scss in and out manually.

Comment: I have the same issue. I would love an answer to this question.